# Generating a back key event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I generate a back key press event through the code in Windows Phone 7 App.

I have an exit button in the app and would like to give it the same functionality as a back button. Basically generating the same event as a back key press would.

Any other ideas on ways to exit and application without actually pressing the back key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`NavigationService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615507.aspx) in your page:

```
if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    this.NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```